# Particular solution to a nonhomogenous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Consider the following ODE:

$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} + kx = f(t)$$

where $$f(t) = \frac{1}{2} +\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{ \frac{-4}{n \pi} \sin\left(\frac{n \pi t}{2}\right)}$$ was derived using fourier series.

I have to find a particular solution. The sum symbol confuses me on this one but I will treat it as one does normally when looking to find a particular solution.

**My thoughts:**

Guess the solution: 
$$ x(t) = A_1 t+ A_0 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{ B \sin\left(\frac{n \pi t}{2}\right) + C \cos\left(\frac{n \pi t}{2}\right)} $$

After taking the second derivative and matching coefficients I arrive to the conclusion that the coefficients of the particular solution are:

$$ A_1 = 0 $$

$$ A_0 = \frac{1}{2k} $$

$$ C = 0 $$

$$ B = - \frac{4}{(k - m (\frac{n \pi}{2})^2)n \pi} $$

Assuming the first and second derivatives are correct is this a correct approach?

Comment: Looks ok to me. I guess you have $k>0$ You can also set $k=\lambda ^2$ and use variation of parameters.

Comment: @Chilango Undetermined comes easier to me. Relieved to know that its right :) Thanks!

Comment: if you use variation of parameters you will see the integrals are all easy because they are of the form sin/sin, sin/cos, etc

Comment: @Chilango I was thinking about $B$. Should I use the sum operator on when determining the coefficients?

Comment: is your diff eq an initial value problem?A boundary value problem?

Comment: @Chilango there are no BC or IC. I have derived $f(t)$ from a periodic function. That is all the info I have!